# How to configure the various PRODUCT_AAPT_ properties for AOSP?

Tags: android-source

I'm looking for an explanation of the following AOSP build properties, what valid values are and how they affect the build and any related properties. I am aware of the system property `ro.sf.lcd_density` but I can't find any official documentation anywhere about these:

```
PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG
PRODUCT_AAPT_PREF_CONFIG
PRODUCT_AAPT_PREBUILT_DPI
```

Comment: One cool trick I just figured out is you can run `get_build_var PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG` to see the value set in your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my experience, and probably should not be the accepted answer as I'm not certain I have the whole story.

**PRODUCT_AAPT_PREF_CONFIG**: The "preferred" resources qualifier. This should be one of the entries in PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG.

**PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG**: an ordered list of the resources qualifier. This acts as a fallback in case the preferred resource qualifier does not exist.

**PRODUCT_LOCALES**: A list of locales that will be included. For whatever reason locales are a special case of resource qualifier.

In my case, I used this:

```
PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG := large xlarge mdpi tvdpi hdpi
PRODUCT_AAPT_PREF_CONFIG := hdpi
PRODUCT_LOCALES := en_US en_GB en_IE de_DE pl_PL pt_BR es_US
```

Our device is TVDPI, but since there are generally no TVDPI specific resources, I picked the next size up as preferred (HDPI). I included "large xlarge mdpi tvdpi hdpi" to allow for a fallback in case there was no HDPI resources.